# Detecting straight line segment in a series

Tags: r

I would like to detect "last" straight line portion in a plot in "R". For example,in the image below, that section would be the one shown under the Red bubble.

[image]

What package or method should I use to first identify that section and then get slope and intercept of the line segment.

Comment: Are you looking for exactly collinear points or approximately collinear points?

Comment: what do you mean by "detect" what's the expected output? binary to say yes or no, or a vector suggesting when it would happen

Comment: How do you define a "straight line portion"?  What do these data represent?  What is the purpose of this detection?  What would be the consequences of false detections or failing to detect such segments?  Why should these plots have *any* straight line portions at all?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @Kodiologist: Approximately collinear points.

Comment: @hxd1011: The expected output is a vector that gives slope and intercept of that segment. The detect essentially means "as a user I wouldn't know when this section starts" and I need to find this in the background code.

Comment: Sorry, the question is still not clear for me. Are you trying to fit a piecewise linear model?

Comment: @whuber: The dataset represent "water-oil ratio" vs "cumulative water injection". The slope and intercept of the straight line is used in another calculation to determine oil rate.  This dataset is for one oil well. If I have 50 wells, I would need an algorithm to determine slope,intercept in the background code. Note that, all curves shall have similar shape, i.e. there will be a straight line portion in the end.

Comment: @hxd1011 : yes. I would think so. I need to identify when that line segment starts and ends. fit a line through it and get slope,intercept.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation--it helps us understand what you need.  I can't avoid wondering, though, how either a water-oil ratio or a cumulative injection amount could possibly be negative, as shown on your plot.

Comment: @whuber: Good question... The dataset is actually Log(cum water injection) on the X axis and Log(water/oil)-1 on the Y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research and found two packages in R that could work in my scenario.

- Segmented
- Strcchange

Eventually I used `segmented` as below:

```
  plot(x,y)
  lin.mod <- lm(y~x)
  m <- mean(x)
  segmented.mod <- segmented(lin.mod, seg.Z = ~x, psi= m)
  sl <- slope(segmented.mod)
  inter <- intercept(segmented.mod)
```

Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Just a few thoughts, open for any suggestions:

- As you know the linear part to always occur at the end, I would naturally start any analysis at the end of the series.
- If there is very little noise in your series at all, you might be able to use a very simplistic approach altogether: take the derivative of your series, then use it to search back to front for the first big change in derivative values. This should happen about at the start of your linear part of the series. Determining the linear fit parameters could then be done using standard techniques.
- A similar approach would be to use the last $n$ values of your series to fit a linear model and remember the error (e.g. RMSE). With repeating this process while increasing $n$ (e.g., quadratically), you could see when the error starts rising. This is going to happen as you reach/overstep the linear part towards the beginning of the series.

  ```
    n     error
    4      0.01
    8      0.02
   16      0.02
   32      0.01
   64      0.08 <-- start of divergence? 
  128       0.2
  256       0.3
  ```

Having found this point, fitting a linear model to all points from there to the end of the series should do the trick. BTW: a similar effect might be visible when monitoring the slope and intercept of the linear model, as the first models will have very similar parameters (could be that you have to normalize them prior to comparison, depending on the implementation you use). But my guess is that the model will of course try to fit the majority of data, so looking at the RMSE might be the better idea.

Comment: Since I am new to R, can you tell me what package might come handy ? @geekoverdose